# JavaScript redirect based on option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect, submit

I need some help with the JavaScript redirect.  I have the following code for the form, but it is not working.

```
<form name="getstarted" width="500">  
    <p>
  
        <select name="trade" id="trade">  
          <option selected="selected" value = "">Please Select License Trade</option>  
          <option value = "A">A-General Engineering</option>  
          <option value = "B">B-General Building</option>  
          <option value = "C2">C2 - Insulation and Acoustical</option>  
        </select>  

    </p>

    <p>Do you currently hold an <strong>active</strong> contractors license in California? <br /> <br />
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="questions" NAME="questions" VALUE="y">Yes
        <INPUT TYPE="radio" id="questions" NAME="questions" VALUE="n">No</p>

     <input type="button" value="Next" onClick = "direction()" />  

</form>

<script language="javascript">  
function direction(value)     
{  
    if((trade == "A") && (questions == "y"))  
    {window.location = "http://localhost:8080/Math/page1.html";}  
      
    else{window.location = "http://localhost:8080/Math/page2.html";}  
}  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".icon a.tooltips").easyTooltip();
        });
</script>
```

I am trying to have this code redirect users based on two different options selected.

Comment: `Is not working` isn't enough. What is happening?

Comment: It takes me to the else location.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function direction(value) {
    var trade = $("#trade").val();
    var questions = $(".questions:checked").val();
    if ((trade == "A") && (questions == "y")) {
        window.location = "http://localhost:8080/Math/page1.html";
    } else {
        window.location = "http://localhost:8080/Math/page2.html";
    }
}
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dAK9f/1/)

What I added:

```
var trade = $("#trade").val();
var questions = $(".questions:checked").val();
```

and removed the duplicate ID and used a class instead:

```
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" class="questions" NAME="questions" VALUE="y"/>Yes
    <INPUT TYPE="radio" class="questions" NAME="questions" VALUE="n"/>No
```

Comment: @LeoVorontsov, happy I could help! please click to accept the answer if it was correct.