# How to redirect a user based on option/select in html (After clicking a button)

Tags: javascript, html

I AM NEW TO THIS AND I DON'T KNOW ANYTHING ABOUT JS OR CSS 
How can I redirect a user to another page depending on the option selected(After the button has been clicked, not after an option has been selected)
For instance, if I select Veg and click the 'Done' button, I should be taken to VegMenu.html and if I select Non-veg, I should be taken to NonVegMenu.html

I tried doing **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388382/javascript-redirect-based-on-option-selected)** but I'm redirected to the page as I select the option which I don't want. I want be redirected after pressing 'Done'

```
<input type="text" name="name"></input>
<br><br>
<select id="Opt">
<option>Veg</option>
<option>Non-Veg</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="age"></input>
<br><br>
<button>Done</button>
```

Comment: Please share what have you tried so far.

Comment: I've edited my question, now you can see what I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With simple javascript:

```js
var makePath = function(form) {
  form.action = document.getElementById('Opt').value;
};
```

```html
<form onsubmit='makePath(this);'>
  <select id="Opt">
    <option value='VegMenu.html' label='Veg' />
    <option value='NonVegMenu.html' label='Non-Veg' />
  </select>
  <button>Done</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was easy to understand

Comment: Arvind, Good alternative. Simple but effective :)  Thanks for sharing.  +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use something similar to this (not tested)

```
<script>
    function redirectMe() {
        var selectedIndex = document.getElementById("Opt").selectedIndex;
        var selectedText = document.getElementById("Opt").options[selectedIndex].text; 

        if (selectedText == "Veg") {
           location.href = "VegMenu.html";
        }
        else {
           location.href = "NonVegMenu.html";
        }
    }
</script>


<select id="Opt">
    <option>Veg</option>
    <option>Non-Veg</option>
</select>

<button onClick="redirectMe()">Done</button>
```

Comment: @Markus Müller this is a Good answer, The only issue i have found with this is that fact it over rides the form validation process.. do you know a way round that?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#but').click(function(e){
  var food = $("#Opt").val();
  if(food == 'Veg')
    location.href = "www.abc.com/veg.html";
  else if (food == "Non-Veg")
    location.href = "www.abc.com/non-veg.html"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Name:
<input type="text" name="name"></input>
<br>
<br>Food:
<select id="Opt">
  <option value="Veg">Veg</option>
  <option value="Non-Veg">Non-Veg</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>Age:
<input type="text" name="age"></input>
<br>
<br>
<button id="but">Done</button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You could also use ` $("#Opt").on("click", function(){});` instead of `$('#but').click(function(e){});`. Then you can do `var food = $(this).val()`

Comment: @AnudeepTubati: The demo is in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
input type="text" name="name"></input>
<br><br>
<select id="Opt">
<option>Veg</option>
<option>Non-Veg</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" name="age"></input>
<br><br>
<button onclick="location.href=(document.getElementById('Opt').selectedIndex==1)?'1.html':'2.html';">Done</button>
```